# Getting data from fragment without loading the view

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, arraylist

I have three fragments inside an activity. Three text views inside this activities. I have three API calls inside each of the fragments. I need the count of ArrayList created in the three fragments. I tried to make the API call in activity and tried to find out the ArrayList from there and passing it to fragment. But I don't know how to pass this type of ArrayList (Arraylist array) to fragment. I only need three integer values in the activity. So the questions are,

1) Please give me a way to pass value from three fragments to activity by actually loading the view of one fragment and loading the rest of the fragment without views.

2) Or give me a way to pass an ArrayList of model-class created at the activity to three fragments.

Comment: add some code snippet so people can help you,,

Comment: My code is confidential that's why sorry for this, but somewhat the answers helping me now, trying to solve this issue and will update as soon as i got it thank you for your response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Get the size of Array from fragment:

In this case you need to get the instance of the added fragment, and retrieve the values you need from it's global variables.

In fragment:

```
public List<MyObject> myList;
```

In Activity:

```
int size;
MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myFragmentTag");
if(fragment != null && is fragment.isAdded())
    size = fragment.myList.size();
```

PS: in the above case don't forget to add a TAG to the fragment when you add it

2 - Pass the Array to fragment:

In this case, you need to make the Object Serializable, add it as an argument to the fragment that is about to be added, and then, when the fragment is added, within the fragment, retrieve the previously added Object

Make the Object Serializable and add it to the Arguments from Activity

In Activity:

```
public MySerializableObjectList myList;
```

Add the array to fragment in Activity:

```
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("myArrayTag", myList);
myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment,"myFragmentTag").commit();
```

In Fragment:

```
public MySerializableObjectList myList;
if(getArguments != null)
    myList = (MySerializableObjectList)getArguments().getSerializable("myArrayTag");

List<MySerializableObject> myListObject;
if(myList != null)
    myListObject = myList.getMySerializableObjectList();
```

Comment: my model class implements parcelable so i am trying to do it as this one, but is there any way like a function call or something @jhon-fredy-trujillo said

Comment: instead of setting putSerializable and getSerializable use putParceable and getParceable, it will work the same way

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

putParcelableArrayList and getParcelableArrayList trough Bundle in the Fragment arguments.

Comment: I was searching for another method actually thank you anyway :)

Comment: Used this method and @Ricardo's answer was more helpful and gave me clear idea thank you Marcos. :)

Comment: No problem, but you should implement Parcelable instead of Serializable

Comment: yeah i used parcelable instead of serializable glad you helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Okey, lets see. In my opinion the best way to do it is query the info in the activity and passing to the fragment, it means, the second way you proposse.

to do this follow this steps
1) Obtain the List in activity onCreate method.
2) In the fragment, Create a variable and a method that recieve the object from the activity.

```
public class FormFragment extends Fragment {
List<Object> data;
 public FormFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
} 
public void initFragment(List<Object> data){
this.data = data
}
}
```

3) After create the fragment, use this method to pass the info to the fragment

```
public class Activity extends AppCompat{
List<Object> data = //Query your data here  
/....

 FormFragment fragment = new FormFragment()
 fragment.init(data)
}
```

and that is all, you can pass the info this way and works smoothly, also, you can use your data from the activity as you bless.

Comment: Fragment fragment = new FormFragment()
 fragment.init(data) //this is not working when i am typing fragment.initFragment it is not showing i made the method public

Comment: oh yeah, let me edit the aswer for you. Remeber this is an example, you must changue as your code is.